# Importing text files into python?

Tags: python

I'm new to the programming game and have been learning python this quarter in school. I'm having some trouble importing and reading a plain text file. For some reason, the code that my teacher wrote works with the plain text file that he also wrote, but when I simply change the name of the file and try to open a different plain text file, I get an error message.

Here is the code from my teacher:

```
fileHandler = open("carBrands.txt","r")
car = fileHandler.readline(4)
print(car)
```

Here is my code:

```
fileHandler = open("cars.txt","r")
car = fileHandler.readline(4)
print(car)
```

As you can see the only thing that I've changed is the file name, but for some reason I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/**********/Downloads/5-13 and 5-15 Files 2/testopen.py", line 2, in <module>
    fileHandler = open("cars.txt")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cars.txt'
```

I've triple checked that there is in fact a 'cars.txt' file, some I'm wondering if anyone can help clear up where I'm making my mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect this is due to you running the program from the wrong directory. The way it's written, you must run the program from the same directory that `cars.txt` is in for it to be found.

Comment: I think this might be it, I didn't know that I had to run them in the same directories. Gonna go try it real quick.

Comment: @HuuNguyen: I would consider putting down your comment as an answer. :D

Answer (score 1):

The path passed into `open` is *relative* to the current working directory. In most cases this is the directory you are in when you run the script, and *not* necessarily the directory the script lives in.

Here's an example -- let's say you have a file `script.py` in a directory `test/` that lives in your home directory, `/home/kellan/`. Its full path is `/home/kellan/test/script.py` then, and it contains the following:

```
fileHandler = open("cars.txt", "r")
car = fileHandler.readline(4)
print(car)
```

Put `cars.txt` in `test/` so that its full path is `/home/kellan/test/cars.txt`. From your home directory, run your script with:

```
python test/script.py
```

This should raise a `FileNotFoundError` or `IOError`.

Now, run `mv test/cars.txt cars.txt` so that `cars.txt` is now in your home directory proper, and run the script again. It should work now because in the script, you are opening a file with a path that is relative to the current working directory.